# how to use javascript to display an image i already have in my html in a div in the same html

Tags: javascript

I have an image in my HTML already. I want to pick this image and display it in a div using Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Comment System</title>
    <style>
        img{
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <img  id="image" src="avataaars.png" alt="profilepicture">
        <textarea name="comment" id="mind" placeholder="what's on your mind"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="post" id="postbtn" value="post" onclick="postmind()" >
    </form>
    <div id="postlist">
    </div>

    <script src="commentproject.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to select from a particular img element and apply to a particular div element:

```
document.getElementById("postlist").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + document.getElementById("image").src + ")";
```

Don't forget to set the height and width on the div (in CSS), or it will be 0x0 and the image won't show.

However, generally I'd recommend obtaining the image URL for the DIV from the place where you got it for the IMG, rather than "copying" between the two like I've shown. But you didn't show much to go on for me to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You write the code. So You know where the image (avataaars.png) stored. You write a Javascript code to load that image from the storage. Then put it in  tag, then in the div you prefer.
That should be the easy and direct one to code.
Any reason why you want to copy the image from the  other div ?